# Display an image and text in a checkbox label using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I display an image with text next to it as the label for a checkbox? I am using Material UI and React. Currently I have this:

```
<FormControlLabel
control={
    <Checkbox checked={false} onChange={this.handleChange('')} value={id} key={id} />
}
label={
    <img src={avatar} key={id} className="profile-img" width="40px" height="auto" style={{marginRight: "5px"}} />
}
```

In the label property I want the image and then a name right next to it, but I can't figure how to properly do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a fragment to also add your text to the label. A fragment is just an empty node that won't show in the DOM allowing you to return multiple JSX components next to each other :

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={
        <Checkbox checked={false} onChange={this.handleChange('')} value={id} key={id} />
    }
    label={
        <>
            <img src={avatar} key={id} className="profile-img" width="40px" height="auto" style={{ marginRight: "5px" }} />
            My text
            {myTextVariable}
        </>
    }
/>
```

If your linter is not a fan of this, you can use `React.Fragment` instead :

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={
        <Checkbox checked={false} onChange={this.handleChange('')} value={id} key={id} />
    }
    label={
        <React.Fragment>
            <img src={avatar} key={id} className="profile-img" width="40px" height="auto" style={{ marginRight: "5px" }} />
            My text
            {myTextVariable}
        </React.Fragment>
    }
/>
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I totally didn't think of using a `React.Fragment`. That worked like a charm. Thanks so much!